# Is it bad practice to use MySQL unsigned integers?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to store integers which will only be positive, and am currently using MySQL.  I made the values UNSIGNED "just in case" I ever had so many records, however, it is doubtful I will ever get there.

I am curious whether it would be better practice to no use the UNSIGNED flag just in case I later wish to change databases to MS SQL, etc which doesn't support unsigned integers.

Is it considered bad practice to use MySQL unsigned integers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to work around unsupported unsigned integer field types in MS SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694/how-to-work-around-unsupported-unsigned-integer-field-types-in-ms-sql)

Comment: It's not considered bad practice. It's actually not considered at all. If you *need* positive numbers, use unsigned, otherwise signed - that's *all there is to it*. If you have some sort of odd project that can swap out for the storage layer and you're doing ultramicrooptimisation such as this one - I'd consider that a bad practice.

Comment: @N.B.  I have no intention to swap out the storage layer, but just never no what the future holds, and would like to mitigate risk where possible.

Comment: MYSQL is NOT SQL Server

Comment: @podiluska.  I don't understand your comment.  Of course it isn't, but it is a potential substitute, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is a bad practice to use data types that are appropriate to the data being stored.

You bring up a very good issue about portability to other databases.  If this is a concern, then you should try to adhere either to ANSI standard functionality or to functionality that you know is similar between the databases.

Moving code from MySQL to SQL Server can involve a lot of more significant effort than just the difference between signed and unsigned integers.  There are numerous places where functions are different, non-existent, or behave different.  Just to give a smattering of examples:

- `cast()` takes different types in MySQL versus SQL Server (`as signed` vs `as int`)
- MySQL has silent error handling in the case of `123 + '456b'` whereas SQL Server will produce an error.
- The string concatenation operator is different in the two databases.
- `datediff()` takes different arguments in the two databases

So, the difference between `signed` and `unsigned` will be a minor concern in a conversion.  You will need to write your code carefully if you are planning such a change.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  Great response. I have no intentions to swap the database, and if I ever do, I will worry about it then.